# How can I attach a scattered object to an animated object?

Tags: animation, objects, add-on, parent

When I scatter my grass object using the free scatter add on within blender, the grass stays static while I roll through my animation. Does anyone know the proper method to attach or parent a scattered object to a mesh so that it stays attached throughout the animation sequence?

[image: start of animation]

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you use geometry nodes? That’s exactly made for these cases.

Comment: You need to parent the scatter objects it has created to the character object

Answer (score 2):

The *Scatter Object* addon will create a series of tris that will stick to the surface of your target object (your character). These tris have *Instancing > Faces* enabled, with your grass object parented to it. By default these tris are not parented to the surface of your target object. What you can do is parent them to your character. You could also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real* and join the grass to the character with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In the modifier stack make sure that the particle modifier is after (under) the armature modifier.

Comment: Scatter Object doesn't use a particle system, it uses instancing  ;)